# Navigation toggle button in bootstrap 3 not dropping down (Javascript issue?)

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Upon making the screen a smaller size, my navigation toggle button is not showing the navigation menu when I click on it. I have racked my brains to solve this and think JavaScript is not active. Despite this, I still cant make it work properly.

JQuery is working and has been placed before JavaScript.
I've tried the web link to JS but this does not seem to work.
I've tried moving the JS files in my folder about and this again doesn't seem to work.

Code is below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<style>

.navbar-brand {font-size:180%;}

.myImage {width:100%;
       height:600px;
       background-size:cover;}

.background {background-color:black;}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="navbar navbar-default">

<div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">

        <div class="navbar-brand"></div>


        <!--Nav toggle button on mobile-->

            <button class="navbar-toggle" 
                    data-toggle="collapse" 
                    datatarget=".navbar-collapse">

                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>

                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>

            </button>

    </div>      

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">

                    <li class="active"><a href="">Home</a>
                    <li class=""><a href="">About</a>
                    <li class=""><a href="">Download</a>

                </ul>

                    <!--log in section-->

                <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">

                    <div class="form-group">

                         <input type="email" 
                                placeholder="Email" 
                                class="form-control">
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">

                         <input type="password" 
                                placeholder="Password" 
                                class="form-control">

                    </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">Log In</button>

                </form>
            </div>

</div>  

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You've made a typo on data-target:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        datatarget=".navbar-collapse">
```

Instead it should be:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle" 
        data-toggle="collapse" 
        data-target=".navbar-collapse">
```